# How to add Combination of uniqueness and add index for two columns in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done the below code within my migration file. But it's not working, and also returns errors. I am also using `scope`.

```
def change
  add_column :load_shortlisted_trucks, :load_id, :integer
  add_index :load_shortlisted_trucks, :load_id, name: "load_id"
  add_column :load_shortlisted_trucks, :company_truck_type_id, :integer
  add_index :load_shortlisted_trucks, :company_truck_type_id, name: "company_id"
  add_index :load_shortlisted_trucks, [:company_truck_type_id, :load_id], unique: true
end
```

Errors :

```
== 20160821065543 AddIndexToLoadShortlistedTrucks: migrating ==================
-- add_column(:load_shortlisted_trucks, :load_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0017s
-- add_index(:load_shortlisted_trucks, :load_id, {:name=>"load_id"})
   -> 0.0545s
-- add_column(:load_shortlisted_trucks, :company_truck_type_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0013s
-- add_index(:load_shortlisted_trucks, :company_truck_type_id, {:name=>"company_id"})
   -> 0.0061s
-- add_index(:load_shortlisted_trucks, [:company_truck_type_id, :load_id], {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: Index name 'index_load_shortlisted_trucks_on_company_truck_type_id_and_load_id' on table 'load_shortlisted_trucks' is too long; the limit is 63 characters
```

Can anyone tell how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the index name of the last `add_index` line. The length of the index name is too long(166 characters). To avoid the migration error, you can pass in a `index` name using the `name` option.

From the documentation,

> add_index
>
> The index will be named after the table and the column name(s), unless you pass :name as an option.

Replace your final `add_index` line with

```
add_index :load_shortlisted_trucks, [:company_truck_type_id,:load_id], unique:true, name: 'my_index_name'
```